# .net 6 web api to OneLogin OIDC challengeasync results in Script is Disabled

Tags: .net-6.0, openid-connect, onelogin

My question is this: based on the following setup, why am I getting a script is disabled? What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Here is the setup: I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with a controller that inherits from `ControllerBase`. This server is meant to act as an authentication server. We are using OneLogin as our OIDC IdP. We are using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` for this, rather than a third party library (please excuse me if my terminology is incorrect. I am a newbie at this).

Note that I can hit a breakpoint in the `Challenge` method of the controller, but OneLogin never hits the callback method.

When I call `ChallengeAsync` in the controller, I get the following display in dev tools/network:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Working...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/2/auth">
            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="a191ac20-4ce8-013c-239a-7a4043bb707b232913"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:21197/oidcauth/callback/"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="openid profile"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="code_challenge" value="1rTHYLlKRSFOR0bF2UcRFA7xwHIbRs1FLI5jqdjHwhY"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="code_challenge_method" value="S256"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="response_mode" value="form_post"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="638335051762872899.MGYwMjMyNzEtMTNmZC00YTMwLTkxMDItMDVmNmE0NDlkZjZhNTU0MjcyYTUtYjA3NC00MzAwLWI4YzEtODFiYzkzZGRjODU1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="state" value="CfDJ8GzhTZwxN6ZJvOF4eiYmv7uE-eZ2daz8RxKi9QKeDklohwRfRozxj6vD3FiOmUh3cB2_e1AWBkTFV0MiPLMu7UHmVVEcO12o6iyAeopTHq0TKHmM6JL1sKLk47a2U8CY6v5PG2WQcx4QmcqQ77VkVItx1c46gxpaX7sKh_wNyv1jA9Tc4AvO_r_8m_j8MkSU8Tq_PIfSDokErCTI8ZdaAeJPu3fc6ITeW_z2bs-FwoGt4cYcTTvWvzKh1p8cfXGlfbV1kb8w1Ki8bOkhWA3BrE9z7tqMSXN4vtEEGOJuR_OBp4LdHRGoBf-oZHf7CFqq_56W1sr7RWFKafNAo1K-_MjtoCdvID8E2WAyMOo9hRf_QNy7KdRpPcnusMAxuF_HiWGZ1EUGxcZYlRo8F8Jz17yXxPSy7_cdq1v9oKL_tSMU"/>
            <noscript>
              **  <p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>**
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </noscript>
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }, 0);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("challenge")]
    public async Task Challenge(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new OpenIdConnectChallengeProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("callback")]
    //[EnableCors("oidc_callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var returnUrl2 = result?.Properties?.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

        var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
     var usrok = accountService.DoesUserHaveAccessToApplication(appusr, "MyApp"))

        return Ok(new { returnUrl = "/", User = "TestUsr" });
    }
```

An extension method to configure my authentication:

```
using Mhk.Authenticate.Server.Contracts;
using Mhk.Authenticate.Server.Models;
using Mhk.Authenticate.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Serilog;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Mhk.Authenticate.Server.Extensions
{
    public static class OIDCServicesExtension
    {
        public static void ConfigureOIDCMiddlewareExtension(this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var tokenValidationClaimsService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ITokenValidationAdditionalClaimsService>();
            var authServerConfig = configuration.GetSection("AuthServerConfig").Get<AuthServerConfig>();
            var ssoconfig = configuration.GetSection("SSOConfig").Get<SSOConfig>();

            var oidcConfig = ssoconfig?.oidc;
            if (oidcConfig == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("SSOConfig.oidc not found"); }

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
                options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext => CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
            });
         
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                //options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;//?TODO: Is this correct?
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                //options.LoginPath = "/oidcauth/challenge";

            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = oidcConfig.MetadataAddress;
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "MyAuthenticateIssuer";

                options.ClientId = oidcConfig.ClientId;
                //options.ClientSecret = oidcConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.UsePkce = true;
                options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.FormPost;
                options.ClaimActions.Add(new IssuerFixupAction());

                // This is the key setup to ensure IdP calls back to the /callback endpoint
                options.CallbackPath = "/oidcauth/callback/";
                var scopes = oidcConfig.Scope;// configuration.GetSection("oidc:scope").GetChildren().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();

                if (scopes != null)
                {
                    options.Scope.Clear();

                    foreach (var scope in scopes)
                    {
                        options.Scope.Add(scope);
                    }
                }

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
                    {
                        Log.Debug(ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                    },
                    OnMessageReceived = async ctx =>
                    {
                        Log.Debug(ctx.Options.Authority);
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                    {
                        Log.Debug("OnTokenValidated");
                        await tokenValidationClaimsService.ValidateTokenAsync(ctx);
                    },
                    OnUserInformationReceived = async ctx =>
                    {
                        Log.Debug(ctx.User.RootElement.ToString());
                    }
                };

                //options.Validate();
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var cert = X509Helper.GetCertificateByThumbprint(authServerConfig.X509CertificateThumbprint);

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(cert))

                    // ... other token validation parameters like ValidateIssuer, ValidateAudience, etc.
                };
            });
        }

        private static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
        {
            if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
            {
                var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

                if (DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
                {
                    options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                }
            }
        }

        // TODO: Use your User Agent library of choice here.
        public static bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Cover all iOS based browsers here. This includes:
            // - Safari on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
            // - WkWebview on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
            // - Chrome on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
            // All of which are broken by SameSite=None, because they use the iOS networking stack
            if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Cover Mac OS X based browsers that use the Mac OS networking stack. This includes:
            // - Safari on Mac OS X.
            // This does not include:
            // - Chrome on Mac OS X
            // Because they do not use the Mac OS networking stack.
            if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") &&
                userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Cover Chrome 50-69, because some versions are broken by SameSite=None, 
            // and none in this range require it.
            // Note: this covers some pre-Chromium Edge versions, 
            // but pre-Chromium Edge does not require SameSite=None.
            if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private class IssuerFixupAction : ClaimAction
        {
            public IssuerFixupAction() : base(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, string.Empty) { }

            public override void Run(JsonElement userData, ClaimsIdentity identity, string issuer)
            {
                var oldClaims = identity.Claims.ToList();

                foreach (var claim in oldClaims)
                {
                    identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value, claim.ValueType, issuer, claim.OriginalIssuer, claim.Subject));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My program file:

```
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Contracts;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Extensions;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Models;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Repository;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Services;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Services.InternalAuth;
using MyExample.Authenticate.Server.Services.OIDCAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var authServerConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthServerConfig").Get<AuthServerConfig>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthServerConfig>(authServerConfig);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOidcConfig, OidcConfig>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISamlConfig, SamlConfig>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISSOConfig, SSOConfig>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleClaimService, RoleClaimService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILoginResultBuilder, LoginResultBuilder>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISecurityTokenOptions, SecurityTokenOptions>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecurityOptions, SecurityOptions>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISecuritySettings, SecuritySettings>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomAppSettings, CustomAppSettings>();
builder.Services.ConfigureDatabase(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenValidationAdditionalClaimsService, TokenValidationAdditionalClaimsService>();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).CreateLogger();

//These are setups for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
//Put in separate extension method...
builder.Services.ConfigureOIDCMiddlewareExtension(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

var isDev = app.Environment.IsDevelopment();

if (isDev)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseCors(); // Ensure CORS middleware is after the custom middleware
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I have tried what is described above. I have tried other configurations, but this is the one that gets me the closest to success.